# Accessing kernel driver data from FIQ interrupt handler failing

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, interrupt

On ARM FIQ interrupts, we have some registers reserved only for FIQ use, and those are a handy way to "save the state" for example of data transfer between FIQ calls.

Currently I'm triggering some `GPIO` pins from the FIQ, and it is working as expected. When setting up the FIQ handler, I pass the pointers to the data registers, that were mapped with ioremap. Working code looks like this:

```
//Driver initialization:
static char* dout0;
static char* din0;
...
static int driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) 
{
struct pt_regs regs;
...
dout0 = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DOUT0, 0xffff);
din0  = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DIN0, 0xffff);
...
regs.ARM_r8 = (long) dout0;
regs.ARM_r9 = (long) din0;
set_fiq_regs(&regs);
...

//In the FIQ handler:
LDR r12, [r8]
ORR r12, r12, #0x20 /* set pin 5 high in dout0 register */
STR r12, [r8]
```

The above code performs as expected, the `pin 5` is set high after FIQ handler is executed.

For more complicated operation, I want to prepare a struct, that will hold data-pointers, and other processing related data, including more mappings to different registers - and pass this to the FIQ handler. But something is going wrong there already when migrating the above code to this.

I modified the code above to look like this

```
//In Driver:
struct fiq_processing {
    char* din0;
    char* dout0;
};

static fiq_processing * pdata; //Pointer to our processing data structure

...
static int driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) 
{
struct pt_regs regs;
pdata = kmalloc(sizeof(*pdata), GFP_KERNEL); //Allocate memory for struct
printk("Size of the data struct %d \n", sizeof(*pdata)); //I get "8" as the size
...
pdata->din0  = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DIN0, 0xffff);
pdata->dout0 = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DOUT0, 0xffff);
...
regs.ARM_r8 = (long) pdata;
set_fiq_regs(&regs);
...

//In the FIQ handler:
#define OFFSET_DIN0 0x0 
#define OFFSET_DOUT0 0x4 //We know size is 8, so offset for dout is half from that
...
LDR r12, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0]
ORR r12, r12, #0x20 /* set pin 5 high in dout0 register */
STR r12, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0] /* This will do nothing ? */
```

After I have allocated the memory for the structure, and mapped the register pointers, I pass the address for pdata structure to the FIQ handler.
In the FIQ handler, I have offsets for `din0` and `dout0`, which I have thought to be `0x0` and `0x4` respectively (deducted from the structure size of 8).

But for some reason, now my FIQ is unable to set the output pin high anymore - I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here..
Am I calculating the offset wrong there ? OR is the call `STR r12, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0]` incorrect ? 
The actual FIQ is somewhat more longer (it reads input state, and input from that creates some conditions), but even basic bit set seems to fail now..

Comment: If the full code isn't behaving as you expect, simplify it until find the piece that's responsible.  Write user-land assembly in a test app if you're not sure of the assembly syntax, or add a bunch more printk's.

Comment: @artlessnoise Hmm, sorry I didn't understand what you mean. In the first case, in the `R8` register I only have the ioremap'ped `HW_PINCTRL_DOUT0` (`DIN0` goes to `R9`). It's true that in struct case, inside the struct the DIN is now first, but in the FIQ handler I'm defining `#define OFFSET_DOUT0 0x4`, so it should be ok, no ?

@Peter, yes, maybe I should try this in user land app, at least debugging would be easier as I wouldn't have to recompile and flash the kernel every time..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Case 1

```
regs.ARM_r8 = (long) dout0;
set_fiq_regs(&regs);
```

...

```
//In the FIQ handler:
LDR r12, [r8]
ORR r12, r12, #0x20 /* set pin 5 high in dout0 register */
STR r12, [r8]
```

Here the value in `r8` is the address of the memory mapped I/O register.  De-referencing it reads from the correct location.

### Case 2

```
struct fiq_processing {
    char* din0;
    char* dout0;
};
static fiq_processing * pdata; //Pointer to our processing data structure
pdata->din0  = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DIN0, 0xffff);
pdata->dout0 = ioremap(HW_PINCTRL_DOUT0, 0xffff);
...
//In the FIQ handler:
LDR r12, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0]
ORR r12, r12, #0x20 /* set pin 5 high in dout0 register */
STR r12, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0] /* This will do nothing ? */
```

In this case, you have retrieved the address of the GPIO controller and your are `ORR`ing with the address!  You need to de-reference once again.

```
LDR r11, [r8, #OFFSET_DOUT0]  # Get address of controller
LDR R12, [R11]                # Get current I/O value.
ORR r12, r12, #0x20           # Set pin 5 high in dout0 register */
STR r12, [r11]                # Write it out.
```

Comment: That makes indeed sense, thanks for the clear example! I will try this as soon as I get back from work today. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, it was indeed this what was wrong! By the way, this might sounds noobish (because it is :P), but I should not touch other registers than FIQ ones in my handler, right ? I seem to cause panics,lockups etc if I touch for example R1 and R2 etc in my handler code.. I guess I should save and restore those registers if I touch them ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  It is also difficult to synchronize the mainline Linux code with your FIQ handler.  I think that the best was is to add an atomic flag to `fiq_processing` that can signal the *FIQ* handler is to stop; or you code the handler to stop when a buffer size is reach, etc.  You can setup `r13`/`sp` to point to a stack and then save `r0-r7` but using these registers is sort of anti-FIQ.  The intent is *super-fast*.  Using anything but `r8-r15`, it would make me wonder why we were using a *FIQ* interrupt; maybe for debug. Typically you need `r0-r7` to call **C** code (no kernel).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I can do with couple registers, to it's enough now that I have this structure pointing working, so I can have read, write and data pointer information easily available, and still have a handle also to the timer registers. Indeed my plan is currently to monitor the buffer size, and when complete, inform my trigger (one of the external timers) to stop counting and triggering the FIQ. The requirement for FIQ is only for some real-time processing, that needs to happen for rouhgly 300ms. Thanks again for your input, it has helped a lot!

Comment: I think that Linux 4+ has better support for FIQ since this answer was created.  Specifically, the Cortex GIC (interrupt controller) might need to use FIQ mode for a *secure world* Linux.  However, this FIQ information might still be useful for older CPUs and older Linux version as well as people with tight real time like conditions.